# Same expression, but takes much less time in a loop on average

Tags: r

I've been trying to find the computational expense with Sys.time(), starting with some simple operations.

I started with something like this

```r
a=c(10,6,8,3,2,7,9,11,13)
t_beginning=Sys.time()
cl2=NULL
indx=which(a==7)
t_ending=Sys.time()
print(t_ending-t_beginning)
```

and it gives me about 0.0023sec after running the code in Rstudio.

Then the code is put into a for loop to find the average expense of the two lines.

```r
sum=0
a=c(10,6,8,3,2,7,9,11,13)

for (i in 1:5) {
  print(i)
  t_beginning=Sys.time()
  cl2=NULL
  indx=which(a==7)
  t_ending=Sys.time()
  sum=t_ending-t_beginning+sum
  print(t_ending-t_beginning)
}
sum/5
```

It turns out that, for every iteration in the for loop, the time consumption is just several milliseconds, much less than what it took as out of the for loop.

```
[1] 1
Time difference of 7.152557e-06 secs
[1] 2
Time difference of 5.00679e-06 secs
[1] 3
Time difference of 4.053116e-06 secs
[1] 4
Time difference of 4.053116e-06 secs
[1] 5
Time difference of 5.00679e-06 secs
```

I expect that the average time cost of the for loop to be about the same as that without a loop, but they are so different. Not sure why this is happening. Can anyone reproduce the same? Thanks!

Comment: The answer below notes that blocking code allows for faster execution. Further, from R 3.4.0 onward, `for` loops have been compiled on the fly in order to execute even faster. On my computer, I get 0.001676559 running the code line by line, 4.386902e-05 by running the code in a block, and between 1.430511e-05 and 6.914139e-06 in the `for` loop iterations.

Comment: I have similar results on R 3.3.3, so not sure if R 3.4.0 is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the way RStudio (or R) runs the code.
The original code is executed line by line, so the timing you get includes interface between RStudio and R.

```
a=c(10,6,8,3,2,7,9,11,13)
t_beginning=Sys.time()
cl2=NULL
indx=which(a==7)
t_ending=Sys.time()
print(t_ending-t_beginning)

# Time difference of 0.02099395 secs
```

If, however, you run all this code at once, by wrapping the code in curvy brackets, the timing you get improve drastically:

```
{
    a=c(10,6,8,3,2,7,9,11,13)
    t_beginning=Sys.time()
    cl2=NULL
    indx=which(a==7)
    t_ending=Sys.time()
    print(t_ending-t_beginning)
}

# Time difference of 0 secs
```

Comment: This is not just rstudio, running the same code in terminal, I get 0.001676559 for the first and 4.386902e-05 for the second.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this

Comment: @lmo, R still runs it line by line, or all at once. Same argument stands.

Comment: @Bulat, what timing do you get?